# How to display database data to another page?

Tags: php, database, html-table

this is my code   for the my table of rooms

```
<?php
    include'db.php';
    $sql=mysql_query("Select*from tb_rooms1");
    echo "<div class='container'>";
    echo "<div class='scrolltable'>";
    echo "<table class= 'table table-striped table-bordered'>";
    echo"<th><div align='center'>ID</div></th>";
    echo"<th><div align='center'>Image</div></th>";
    echo"<th><div align='center'>Room Name</div></th>";
    echo"<th><div align='center'>Description</div></th>";
    echo"<th><div align='center'>Price Per Night</div></th>"; 
    echo"<th><div align='center'>Status</div></th>";
    echo"<th><div align='center'>Reserve</div></th>";

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        @$id=$row['eid'];

        echo"<tr align='center'>";
        echo"<td><div style='font-size:11px;' align='center'>".$row['roomID']</div></td>";
        echo"<td><div style='font-size:11px;' align='center'><img width=72 height=52 alt='Unable to View' src=".$row['image']."></div></td>";
        echo"<td><div style='font-size:11px;' align='center'>".$row['name']."</div></td>";
        echo"<td><div style='font-size:11px;' align='center'>".$row['description']."</div></td>";
        echo"<td><div style='font-size:11px;' align='center'>".$row['price']."</div></td>";
        echo"<td><div style='font-size:11px;' align='center'>".$row['status']."</div></td>";
        echo"<td><div align='center' style='margin-top:30px'><input style='margin-top:-2px;' type='checkbox'></div></td>";
    }
    echo"</table>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"</div>";
?>
```

I don't know how can I display the Information of the room I have selected to another page. Can someone help me?  I'm

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific, are you trying to make each room clickable?

Answer (score 0):

Make your room clickable and pass the room id through as a parameter

```
echo"<td><div style='font-size:11px;' align='center'><a href='otherpage.php?roomid={$row['roomID']}'> Room {$row['roomID']}</a></div></td>";
```

In your other php document you would have something like this:

```
otherpage.php
<?php
include'db.php';
$roomid = $_GET['roomid'];
$lookupQuery = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tb_rooms1 WHERE roomID = [$roomid]");
```

... Display the data however you want

One thing you will need to look into is mysql injection since you're code is using mysql and parameters are being passed straight into your query...

Comment: I would like to use checkbox. So when I clicked that and reserved. It will display the details about the room I have selected. Can you please help me?